# Can't log in to my Spring app in chrome/chromium after disabled SSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have very weird problem. I disabled SSL and change port from 443 to 8181 in my `application.properties` and now I can't login to my app in chrome/chromium browsers. On Firefox everything work well. I tried to delete all browser data and `mvn clean install` command. Nothing work. I don't have any error in browser console and Spring console. Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Show your login screen with uri.

Comment: @AjayKumar Can you tell me why? I can't even log in with standard spring security login screen.

Comment: Because “why” itself embeds lots of questions. See, dude here on SO there is no magic to read your mind. Its a community effort to resolve issues and specially you being a senior member of it, it becomes each of us’s responsibility to give as much relevant information as possible. Thats “why”.!